# How can I create a window that overlays the desktop on OS X?

Tags: macos, core-graphics, nswindow

I want to make a transparent window that overlays all of the screens on OS X that I can draw to. I'm new to OS X development, so I don't really understand how all the AppDelegate and NSWindow stuff interacts.

Comment: can you elaborate a little more on what you mean by "overlay"?  do you want to obscure or hide the desktop?  or do you just want to have a transparent window (where the desktop and everything else appears normally underneath)?

Comment: Ah, sorry, I want a transparent window, so you would be able to see the desktop through it (except where something was drawn).